# Ellipses and Parentheses and Period

Tags: punctuation

After the word *her*, the ellipses does not have a space before or after the parentheses. Correct format please re spacing ... and space before parentheses?

Also, should there be a period after the parentheses?

> As I got into the car to head toward the Bronx, I began having a series of rushed and overwhelming thoughts and feelings. (Someone had kidnapped my mother, she was lying sick on the floor and could not reach the phone, a car had hit her…) And I started crying but could hear my mother voice her words of wisdom.

Comment: Hi Stuart. Thanks for the link. I read it over a zillion times and could not find anything about ellipses and parentheses. This is my query - her…) - space after her? - I think yes. Space after ellipses and before the parentheses? Period after the parentheses? I am doing editing for someone and need to be correct. Thanks muchly to you and everyone else. My head hurts.

Comment: The parens don’t belong there.

Comment: No space before the closing parenthesis, and no additional period.